Page number starts at zero for numbering scheme based on section number and relative page count
I have tried to replicate a different type of page numbering scheme, which uses the section number and the page within the section, for example, 2-1 for the first page in the second section, or 1-5 for the fifth page in the first section. To do this I tried to follow this answer Latex page numbering by section, which states that one must work around pages starting at 0 for sections. I tried to use this workaround but it didn't work for me, and the page starts at (e.g.) 2-0 for the "normal" \section command.
I also have a custom environment ("custom content" as shown below) that adds a "title page" for lists that are not really sections, but they appear in the TOC as such using \phantomsection. This title page has the starting index 0 within its section, but it still appears as I want it in the TOC, with hyperlink to the first content page of the section.

Besides the code extracted from the above answer, I had a solution that made the first section appear on page s-1 in the TOC, but it was incremented for each section and subsection. This was using the following line
\apptocmd{\@sect}{\stepcounter{page}}{}{}%

How can I keep the page numbering as-is for my phantomsections, but start the page count for actual sections at 1 (and not 0)?
The current shortened and simplified version of my document is given below. It may define some weird environments, but they have more stuff in them in my original document than in this MWE.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=0.75in,
    right=0.75in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\maketoc}{%
    \begin{titlepage}%
    \begingroup%
        \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}% Page numbering style
        \thispagestyle{preface}%
        \begingroup%
            \tableofcontents%
        \endgroup%
    \endgroup%
\end{titlepage}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Tried to follow this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210871/latex-page-numbering-by-section
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\numberwithin{page}{section}% Number page by section
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}% Page numbering style
    \pagestyle{plain}%
}%

\newcounter{topic}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Tried to follow this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210871/latex-page-numbering-by-section
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Make sure that page starts from 1 with every \section
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
{\protected@edef}% <search>
{%
    \def\arg{#1}\def\arg@{\@sect}%
    \ifx\arg\arg@\setcounter{page}{2}\fi%
    \protected@edef%
}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>

\define@key{customcontent@keys}{title}{\def\customcontent@title{#1}}

\define@key{customlist@keys}{title}{\def\customlist@title{#1}}
\define@key{customlist@keys}{description}{\def\customlist@description{#1}}

\define@key{baselist@keys}{label}{\def\baselist@label{#1}}

\newenvironment{baselist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{baselist@keys}{label=\alph*,#1}%
    \begingroup%
    \small%
    \vspace{-\parskip}%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\baselist@label.,leftmargin=*,labelindent=1.5em,topsep=4pt,itemsep=3pt,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1.5pt,align=right]%
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
    \vspace{-\parskip}%
    \endgroup%
}%

\newenvironment{customlist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{customlist@keys}{title=,description=,#1}%
    \stepcounter{topic}
    \begingroup%
    \small%
    \colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][c]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\customlist@title}}}}%
    \phantomsection%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{topic}~~{\customlist@title}}%
    \customlist@description%
    \begin{baselist}[label=\arabic*]%
}{%
    \end{baselist}%
    \endgroup%  
}%

\NewEnviron{customcontent}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{customcontent@keys}{title=,#1}%
    \setcounter{topic}{0}
    \newpage%
    \phantomsection%
    \stepcounter{section}%
    \thispagestyle{blank}%
    \begin{titlepage}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{center}%
    {\Huge\MakeUppercase{\customcontent@title}}%
    \end{center}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \end{titlepage}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}\customcontent@title}%
    \BODY%
    \newpage%
}

\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{preface}{%
    \pagenumbering{roman}%
    \fancyhead{}%
    \fancyfoot{}%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\hspace{2em}\thepage{}}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{Custom preface footer}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%        
    \fancyhead{}%
    \fancyfoot{}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{Custom plain footer}%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\hspace{2em}\thepage{}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\fancypagestyle{blank}{%        
    \fancyhead{}%
    \fancyfoot{}%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\hspace{2em}\thepage{}}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{This should be blank, but is shown here to indicate the page number. }%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}%

\title{Document title}
\author{Document author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage
\maketoc

\section{First standard section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Second standard section}
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage

\section{Third standard section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{customcontent}[title={First custom content}]
    \begin{customlist}[title={First topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \begin{baselist}
            \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
            \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \end{baselist}
    \end{customlist}
    \begin{customlist}[title={Second topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
\end{customcontent}

\begin{customcontent}[title={Second custom content}]
    \begin{customlist}[title={First topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
    \begin{customlist}[title={Second topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
    \begin{customlist}[title={Third topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
    \begin{customlist}[title={Fourth topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
\end{customcontent}

\section{Fourth standard section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}


Article class does not use \@sect but rather handles everything using \@startsection.

Also, \tableofcontents uses \section*, which would therefore also reset the page counter.

This redefines \section (but not \section*) to reset the page counter to one.  I also experimented regarding local vs. global changes, so may have changed more than needed.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=0.75in,
    right=0.75in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{topic}

\pagestyle{plain}%
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}% Page numbering style

\makeatletter
\let\oldsection=\section
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar{\oldsection*}{\setcounter{page}{1}\oldsection}}

\define@key{customcontent@keys}{title}{\def\customcontent@title{#1}}

\define@key{customlist@keys}{title}{\def\customlist@title{#1}}
\define@key{customlist@keys}{description}{\def\customlist@description{#1}}

\define@key{baselist@keys}{label}{\def\baselist@label{#1}}

\newenvironment{baselist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{baselist@keys}{label=\alph*,#1}%
    \begingroup%
    \small%
    \vspace{-\parskip}%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\baselist@label.,leftmargin=*,labelindent=1.5em,topsep=4pt,itemsep=3pt,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1.5pt,align=right]%
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
    \vspace{-\parskip}%
    \endgroup%
}%

\newenvironment{customlist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{customlist@keys}{title=,description=,#1}%
    \stepcounter{topic}
    \begingroup%
    \small%
    \colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][c]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\customlist@title}}}}%
    \phantomsection%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{topic}~~{\customlist@title}}%
    \customlist@description%
    \begin{baselist}[label=\arabic*]%
}{%
    \end{baselist}%
    \endgroup%  
}%

\NewEnviron{customcontent}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{customcontent@keys}{title=,#1}%
    \setcounter{topic}{0}
    \newpage%
    \phantomsection%
    \stepcounter{section}%
    \thispagestyle{blank}%
    \begin{titlepage}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{center}%
    {\Huge\MakeUppercase{\customcontent@title}}%
    \end{center}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \end{titlepage}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}\customcontent@title}%
    \BODY%
    \newpage%
}

\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{preface}{%
    %\pagenumbering{roman}% appears to be global
    \fancyhead{}%
    \fancyfoot{}%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\hspace{2em}\thepage{}}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{Custom preface footer}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%        
    \fancyhead{}%
    \fancyfoot{}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{Custom plain footer}%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\hspace{2em}\thepage{}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\fancypagestyle{blank}{%        
    \fancyhead{}%
    \fancyfoot{}%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\hspace{2em}\thepage{}}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{This should be blank, but is shown here to indicate the page number. }%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}%

\title{Document title}
\author{Document author}

\pagestyle{plain}% default
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}% Page numbering style
  \pagestyle{preface}%
  \maketitle
  \clearpage
  \tableofcontents%
\end{titlepage}%

\section{First standard section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Second standard section}
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage

\section{Third standard section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{customcontent}[title={First custom content}]
    \begin{customlist}[title={First topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \begin{baselist}
            \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
            \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \end{baselist}
    \end{customlist}
    \begin{customlist}[title={Second topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
\end{customcontent}

\begin{customcontent}[title={Second custom content}]
    \begin{customlist}[title={First topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
    \begin{customlist}[title={Second topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
    \begin{customlist}[title={Third topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
    \begin{customlist}[title={Fourth topic}]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
        \item\textbf{Some item}\newline\lipsum[1]
    \end{customlist}
\end{customcontent}

\section{Fourth standard section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}


Thank you! All of your changes worked perfectly.
